# Denormalizing the prediction of NN to its actual scale

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, denormalization

I'm working on a time series prediction problem. I'm using a simple DNN and have normalized my input and target. I'm getting
decent results in terms of fluctuations and trend. However, I don't know how to invert the prediction to its actual scale to match it to my real(non-normalized) time series. I tried multiplying to the standard deviation and adding the mean I used to normalize my input but the prediction and the data are still too different in terms of magnitude. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
'''python
# Data is a 36*3500 matrix each row contains the features of 3500 days of observation(Google Stock index Close, High, Low, Open). Target is the next day Pc.
    
dataset = Data.values
    
    
TRAIN_SPLIT = int(0.7 * len(dataset[1:, 3]))
Val_split = int(0.9 * len(dataset[1:, 3]))
    
data_mean = dataset[:TRAIN_SPLIT].mean(axis=0)
data_std = dataset[:TRAIN_SPLIT].std(axis=0)
dataset = (dataset - data_mean) / data_std
    
Y = np.array(dataset[1:, 3])
dataset = dataset[:-1, :]
X = dataset

Y_train = Y[:TRAIN_SPLIT]
X_train = X[:TRAIN_SPLIT, :]

Y_test = Y[TRAIN_SPLIT:Val_split]
X_test = X[TRAIN_SPLIT:Val_split, :]

Y_val = Y[Val_split:]
X_Val = X[Val_split:, :]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2()))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2()))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2()))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics= ['mae', 'mape'])
    
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=10, 
validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), verbose=1)
    
p = model.predict(X_Val)
plt.figure(figsize=(11, 5), dpi=120)
plt.plot(p/max(p))
plt.plot(np.array(data['Close'][-398:])/max(np.array(data['Close'][-398:])))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

'''
[Orange line the the real data and the blue line is the prediction(both normalized to 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrmDK.png)

Comment: Can you include code for what you've tried?

Comment: @jdaz This is my code.
Thank you